How to use MUI-lab-tabs + React Router V6 ScrollRestoration
@mui/lab offers utility components that inject props to implement accessible tabs following WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices. document
I am using mui lab tabs.
const tabs = [
  {value: "/", label: "home"},
  {value: "/hot-hub", label: "hot hub post"},
  {value: "/source", label: "Source"},
  {value: "/article", label: "artcile"}
]


const MobileMain = memo(({}: Props) => {

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const location = useLocation()

  const tabPanelSX = {height: "100%", padding: 0}

  return (
    <div className="h-full flex flex-col">
      <TabContext value={location.pathname}>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
          <TabList onChange={(e, value) => {
            navigate(value)
          }}
          >
            {
              tabs.map(tab => <Tab key={tab.value} value={tab.value} label={tab.label}/>)
            }
          </TabList>
        </Box>
        {
          tabs.map(tab => <TabPanel key={tab.value} value={tab.value} sx={tabPanelSX}><Outlet/></TabPanel>)
        }
      </TabContext>
    </div>
  )

})

I want to use <ScrollRestoration /> to save the scroll position. But I don't know where should I put <ScrollRestoration />? what's is root route?

You should only render one of these and it's recommended you render it in the root route of your app. document
import { ScrollRestoration } from "react-router-dom";

function RootRouteComponent() {
 return (
   <div>
     {/* ... */}
     <ScrollRestoration />
   </div>
 );
}


I hope that when the user switches to tab B and then switches back to tab A, the scroll position of tab A remains unchanged.
what should I do?

Update 2024-6-28 10:22:08
RouterProvider
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
        <ScrollRestoration />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  )


Render the ScrollRestoration in the root route component, e.g. the component at the root of your routing configuration. I don't think ScrollRestoration will work like you are expecting since it works on the entire window view instead of within individual elements that are scrollable. For this you'd need to likely track and maintain the independent scroll offsets for each tab you wish to restore scroll position to.

@DrewReese I added a piece of code. Is  placed like this?

ScrollRestoration should be rendered in the router, not adjacent to it. As the documentation suggests, typically you render ScrollRestoration in the root route component.
Example:
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  Outlet,
  ScrollRestoration,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const RootLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Outlet />
    <ScrollRestoration />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      // ... all the app routes
    ],
  },
]);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


<TabPanel><Outlet/><ScrollRestoration /></TabPanel> I put it like this and it doesn't seem to work. Is it impossible to use MUI tabs + React Router ScrollRestoration?

@SageJustus What specifically isn't working as you are expecting? Think you could create a running Codesandbox demo of the code you are working with that reproduces the issue or problem you still have, with clear reproduction steps, that we could inspect live?

I created a codesandbox. I found that all tabs share the same scroll position, which is inconsistent with the expectation that each tab has an independent scroll position.
